# How to apply parent data attribute value to dynamically inserted button

Tags: jquery

I have some markup like this:

```
<table id="fcm_table">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="hs_button" data-buttonID="<?php echo $buttonID; ?>"></td>
        </tr>
        //multiple instances of the <tr><td> in the table
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I need to insert an anchor tag in the `<td>` and apply the "button ID" as the `href`, however I cannot target the parent td's `data-buttonID` value. I keep getting undefined.

```
function hs_button_dyn() {
   var button_ID = $(this).parent('td.hs_button').data('buttonID');
   var content = '<a id="bar" href="' + button_ID + '">foo</a>';
   $('#fcm_table tbody tr td.hs_button').prepend(content);
}

$(function(){
    hs_button_dyn();
});
```

Comment: `data-` attributes must be lower case

Comment: More specifically to your issue - what exactly do you think `this` is when you're using it?

Comment: You have an obscure reference to `this` inside the function. What did you want `this` to represent?

Comment: Change `$(this).parent("td.hs_button")` to `$('#fcm_table tbody tr td.hs_button')`

Comment: changing $(this) to the acutual identifier worked in populating the button. I have multiple instances of the td in question, and it was applying the same value to all - not taking it from the button's parent td - just taking it from the first td

Comment: Yes, @Twisty 's solution will allow you to call it for multiple if you wrap a loop around the hs_button_dyn call

Comment: when I wrap it in an .each function, I get the same number of buttons in each td as there are td's to apply it to. Im missing something obviously

Comment: With Twisty's solution you would do:  `$("'#fcm_table tbody tr td.hs_button'").each((i, e) => hs_button_dyn(el))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your `hs_button_dyn();` call so that `this` *does* refer to each `td`:

```
$('#fcm_table tbody tr td.hs_button').each(hs_button_dyn);
```

now, inside `hs_button_dyn`, `this` will refer to each `.hs_button` in turn.  You can then use that to add a button inside each td:

```js
function hs_button_dyn() {
   // `this` is the `td`
   var button_ID = $(this).data('buttonid');
   var content = '<a id="bar" href="' + button_ID + '">foo (' + button_ID + ')</a>';
   $(this).prepend(content);
}

$('#fcm_table tbody tr td.hs_button').each(hs_button_dyn);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="fcm_table">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="hs_button" data-buttonid="#ID1"> x</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="hs_button" data-buttonid="#ID2"> x</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="hs_button" data-buttonid="#ID3"> x</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Note that the call to `.data("buttonid")` must be lowercase, but it doesn't matter if your `data-buttonID` matches the case, as long as you use `.data(lowercase)`.   `.data("buttonID")` will always be undefined.

Comment: Thank you all for your help, I learned a lot. Using this answer, I can get to where I need to go.

Comment: Note that `id="bar"` will generate multiple elements with the same ID - IDs must be unique.  I've not changed that above as it's not specific to the question, but advising here.  You probably don't need an `id=` on that `<a>` at all.

Comment: I can navigate around the ID, but .prepend() is not inserting it to be the first child of the td. It is inserting it after a couple text nodes, any ideas?

Comment: Your `td` in the code was empty, so .prepend / .append would do the same thing.  I used .append above when updating, are you using .prepend in your own code?

Comment: I've updated the snippet to use prepend with some existing text, also here: https://jsfiddle.net/dxqfkhws/

Comment: I was applying .prepend in the .each call. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
$(function(){
  function hs_button_dyn(el) {
    $("<button>", {
      id: "bar"
      href: $(el).data("buttonID")
    }).html("foo").prependTo(el);
  }
  hs_button_dyn('#fcm_table tbody tr td.hs_button');
});
```

In your code, `this` would reference the Function and not an Element in the page. So this is not useful to you.

You can pass in an element and then perform the updates you want.

**Update**

If you have multiple TDs, can loop it:

```
$(function(){
  function hs_button_dyn(el, c) {
    $("<button>", {
      id: (c == undefined ? "bar" : "bar-" + c),
      href: $(el).data("buttonID")
    }).html("foo").prependTo(el);
  }
  $('#fcm_table tbody tr td.hs_button').each(function(i, elem){
    hs_button_dyn(elem, (i + 1));
  });
});
```

If you're getting other errors, can try reading it as an Attribute:

```
href: $(el).attr("data-buttonID")
```

Comment: Minor note: in OPs code, `this === window` not "the function"  https://jsfiddle.net/zwdmy2os/1/

Comment: I keep getting "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier" for the buttonid value

Comment: They are both changed to buttonid and still get error

Comment: Still get "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier" -> href: $(el).attr("data-buttonid") with either attr or data

Comment: @freedomn-m thanks for that tidbit. *Inside a function, the value of `this` depends on how the function is called. Since the following code is not in strict mode, and because the value of this is not set by the call, this will default to the global object, which is window in a browser.*

Comment: @DirtyBirdDesign Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example